# Расположение блока на странице

Tags: html, css, css3

Создал блок, а вот расположить его по-центру не могу, выравнивается только текст, а вот блок целиком не знаю как.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  background: #D2B48C;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="сontainer-menu">
  <div class="Menu-Main">Главная</div>
  <div class="Menu-Contacts">Контаты</div>
  <div class="Menu-Feedback">Обратная связь</div>
  <div class="Menu-Reviews">Отзывы</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Расположить по центру ЧЕГО? В этом идея.

Comment: расположить по центру экрана

Comment: вот html code:  <div class = "Container-Menu">
                <div class = "Menu-Main" >Главная</div>
                <div class = "Menu-Contacts" >Контаты</div>
                <div class = "Menu-Feedback" >Обратная связь</div>
                <div class = "Menu-Reviews" >Отзывы</div>

Comment: да, вот css code: div{
    text-align: center;
    background:  #D2B48C;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}

Comment: @Дима, если вам помогло чьё-то решение, то отметьте его "галочкой"

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `display: flex`:

```css
.container-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-menu>div {
  background: #D2B48C;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-menu">
  <div class="Menu-Main">Главная</div>
  <div class="Menu-Contacts">Контаты</div>
  <div class="Menu-Feedback">Обратная связь</div>
  <div class="Menu-Reviews">Отзывы</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Опередил меня на три секунды)))), писал второй вариант...

Comment: @Air, будешь третий писать, про `position: absolute`?))))

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов куча, это один из них `margin: auto;`

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  background: #D2B48C;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container-Menu">
  <div class="Menu-Main">Главная</div>
  <div class="Menu-Contacts">Контаты</div>
  <div class="Menu-Feedback">Обратная связь</div>
  <div class="Menu-Reviews">Отзывы</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка в том, что в css выбираете все теги div, в эту выборку попадают все дочерние и родительский блок. Лучше всем дочерним блокам дать общий класс, к примеру class="menu" и в стилях обращаться к нему. И если все таки inline-block у дочерних блоков, то вариант такой

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  background: #D2B48C;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu menuMain">Главная</div>
  <div class="menu menuContacts">Контаты</div>
  <div class="menu menuFeedback">Обратная связь</div>
  <div class="menu menuReviews">Отзывы</div>
</div>
```

Comment: В описании все верно, я тоже так считаю, только не понятно, почему блок не по середине? И зачем дочерним блокам ` position: relative;`?

Comment: Сей вариант не работает. `text-align: center;` должен быть применен к родителю.